# Activity Monitor - Google Chrome taking a lot of memory

Tags: google-chrome, process, ram

My macbook started freezing recently and I thought it might be due to shortage of memory. So I opened the activity monitor for the first time and I noticed there are some weird things happening with Chrome. Why are there so many Google Chrome Helper processes??

Is there any reason why there as so many processes?

[image: Activity Monitor]

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, for one, each tab of Chrome runs independently. So you'll see quite a few processes running due to that.

Another thing to keep in mind is extensions. Each of them usually run in their own process as well. If you have a lot of extensions running, they add up rather quickly.